# how can i edit ip address of raspberryPi in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, raspberry-pi

i want change ip address, subnet mask and gateway of Pi3 in node js.

i used module '`network-config`' and wrote and executed the code below.

```
var networkconfig = require('network-config');

networkconfig.configure('eth0',{

ip:         192.168.1.111,
netmask:    255.255.255.0,
gateway:    192.168.1.1,

},function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

but an error has occurred.

```
{Error: EACCES: permisiion denied, open '/etc/network/interfaces'
error:-13,
code:'EACCES',
syscall:'open',
path:'/etc/network/interfaces'}
```

I do not seem to have access, how do I get permission?

Or is there another way edit Pi's IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute nodeJS with sudo "sudo node file.js"